# Small (Micro) 16GB USB flash drive

Tags: usb, hardware-rec, usb-flash-drive, product-rec

I'm looking for a small 16GB USB flash drive, that's good looking, will stand the test of time and can be attached to a key ring.

I don't want extra software (like that found on the [SanDisk Micro Cruzer](http://www.amazon.co.uk/SanDisk-16GB-Micro-Cruzer-Retail/dp/B001CHWE9U/)) and it needs to be compatible with Windows, Mac and Linux.

Also, I'd rather pay a bit more than buying a cheap flash drive and then it crapping out on me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't the most beautiful thing in the world, but it can be attached to a key ring and will definitely last you a long time. The [Corsair 16GB Survivor](http://www.corsair.com/products/survivor/default.aspx) was built with durability in mind:

> - Encased in extremely strong CNC-milled, anodized aircraft-grade
>     aluminum.
> - Water resistant to 200M through the use of a EPDM waterproof seal.
> - Protected from vibration or impact damage through the use of a molded
>     shock dampening collar.
> - Plug-&-Play with any USB 2.0 certified peripheral computer port
>     (backward compatible with USB 1.1).
> - USB extension cable and Dog Tags included.
> - Protected by a Limited 10-year Warranty.

For a smaller stylish drive, Sony makes a [16GB Micro Vault Click](http://www.sonystyle.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?storeId=10151&catalogId=10551&langId=-1&productId=8198552921665428499) USB Flash drive that clicks like a pen to expose the USB connector.

Comment: +1 Anything encased in CNC-machined aluminum has to be awesome.

Comment: Whilst it isn't small the 10 year warranty is very good and it looks like it'll take a few knocks without any bother.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [SuperTalent STU16GPCN Pico-C Nickel Plated 16 GB USB 2.0 Flash Drive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001UO6CLG). It's well reviewed and incredibly small (31.3 x 12.4 x 3.4 mm).

Comment: I have one of these (albeit 8GB) and it's great.  No cap to lose; the ring is part of the metal shell, so it's remarkably unlikely to break off.  The first one I got just completely stopped responding once I tried to put a lot of data on it.  The second has been fine for a year or so.  So make sure you stress-test it.  The chain that comes with it is crap.  I ordered some titanium rings from theringlord.com to make my own chain.

Comment: Oh, and it's honest-to-god metal.  There are some obvious plastic bits, but it's nigh unbreakable.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Transcend T3](http://www.transcendusa.com/Products/ModDetail.asp?ModNo=181) -- works fine on all systems with good transfer speeds.
Only sad thing, it does not seem to be available in 16GB yet.

But, there is the [PNY Micro Attache](http://www3.pny.com/category_buymulti.aspx?Category_ID=395) which is easily available in 16GB sizes.
Works well too. And, to be safe, you could keep your data backed up (and encrypted).

The above two models are really tiny (usually referred as Micro USB drives).
I prefer to carry mine in the wallet.

But, all said, the [SanDisk Ultra Titanium Cruzer 16GB](http://www.sandisk.co.uk/Products/Item%282729%29-SDCZ7-016G-E11-Cruzer_Titanium_USB_Drive_16GB.aspx) is really cool.
Particularly, if you are looking at rough use.

Comment: The Transcend T3 looks really good, I might just have to pick one up for the hell of it, also I've changed the title to include the word Micro.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your choice of the many USB drives out there, remember, any of them can be formatted to remove any extra software included.

The U3 software (SanDisk and some others use this software) can be removed by small utility available for free. For Sandisk drives, you can get it off their website. Note: Simple drive formatting will not remove the U3 software.

http://apac.sandisk.com/Retail/Default.aspx?CatID=1415

Comment: only works on windows...

Comment: True, that is just Sandisks official software though. If anyone has any other removal tool links, feel free to add them to this answer.